# Lebesgue-integrating a non-Riemann integrable function

Tags: lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

In my limited experience, I've only seen Lebesgue integration theory used to prove things that rely at the base on a normal integral using anti-differentiation, which is thus indistinguishable from the process of Riemann integration.

Does anyone know of an example of actually integrating a non-Riemann-integrable function using Lebesgue integration, using the actual limit defn of the integral?

EDIT:
Looking for one with an integral that is not 0 or 1 :)

Comment: $I_A(x)$ for sets $A$ like $\mathbb{Q}$ are the most common examples of functions which are non Riemann integrable but are integrable (L).

Answer (score 3):

The function $$f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R, f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, \text{ if $x \in \mathbb Q$} \\ 0, \text{ if $x \notin \mathbb Q$} \end{cases}$$

is not Riemann intégrable (upper sum $1$, lower sum $0$). But Lebesgue intégrable with integral $0$ obviously.

Comment: thanks, I should have clarified I'm looking for ones where the limit isn't as easy to see - I've just edited my question to include the constraint that the integral is neither 0 nor 1

Comment: I mean technically an example for which the integral is neither 0 nor 1 could be the same function but replace "1" with "2". I'm guessing you want something more "interesting" and not a piecewise function?

Comment: basically, yeah.