# A non-Riemann integrable function that is Lebesgue integrable

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration

I'm seeking a function that is non-Riemann integrable yet Lebesgue integrable.  [Everyone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2611331/lebesgue-integrating-a-non-riemann-integrable-function) seems to illustrate this phenomenon with the indicator function applied to rational numbers.

Is there another such function... perhaps one that would be of greater interest and background to students... one that can be (approximately) plotted?

We need an uncountable number of singularities.  A function such as $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sin 1/x}$ on $[0,1]$ (plotted) has an infinite number of discontinuities, but these can be counted.

[image]

Comment: Do you consider indicator functions of fat cantor sets "of greater interest" to students?  It's a less trivial example, as if I'm not making a mistake, it has no riemann-integrable version.  If that doesn't fit, can you explain what you mean by "of greater interest"?

Comment: A function $[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is Riemann integrable (RI) if and only if it is bounded and the set of discontinuities is at most countable. If we look for examples that aren't bounded, you might say then you want a function which is Lebesgue integrable, but not improperly Riemann integrable. If you are content with a bounded example, then by the characterization of RI, it has to have many discontinuities, so an indicator function of a measurable set with uncountably many discontinuities is very natural.

Comment: This post suggests that we only care about Lebesgue integration because it can handle more functions than Riemann integration, namely seemingly contrived functions. While true, a more important reason is the generality of the Lebesgue integral to functions whose domain does not have a natural way to partition into rectangles, and the stability of Lebesgue integrable functions under limits. To me, this is much better motivation than saying that one can integrate the indicator of the rationals.

Comment: @AndrewZhang:  I'll give some context.  I'll be teaching an advanced course on Fourier transforms and a key step in one or two derivations is the interchange of summation and integration.  This is one class of problems where Lebegue integration is ultimately needed.  I will illustrate the classic difference between Riemann and Lesbegue integration graphically, with the classic "vertical slices" versus "horizontal slices" for computing the area under a curve.  Fine.  But students will surely want an example where Riemann fails.  I thought $\frac{1}{\sin 1/x}$, but no it won't.

Comment: Well, the rational indicator hints at the deeper reasons for the success of Lebesgue integration, which is that it partitions the domain far more finely that Reimann  integration does. While I would not know how to prove such a statement, I imagine that any bounded non Reimann integrable function would also be unplottable.

Comment: @copper.hat:  You may be right... but I wrote "(approximately) plotted."  By that I mean a function such as $\frac{1}{\sin 1/x}$, which of course cannot be plotted "at" $0$, but students can surely understand the idea.  (I'll add a plot to the problem, above...)

Comment: Unbounded I see. Where are the uncountably many points of discontinuity? Am I being dense (pun intended)?

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Aren’t there uncountable sets of measure zero? I question the correctness of your statement.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Are you considering $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sin(1/x)}$ as a function into the extended reals $f: (0, 1] \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$? Even then the set of discontinuities is countable.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The points of discontinuity of $1/\sin(1/x)$ come from the zeros of $\sin(1/x)$ which are countable.  The issue with $1/\sin(1/x)$ is a problem for **both** [improper] riemann-integrability and lebesgue-integrability.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Yes, thanks for catching that. I definitely meant to say "bounded and whose set of discontinuities has measure zero."

Comment: Ah yes, the discontinuities of $\frac{1}{\sin 1/x}$ are infinite, yet countable, so that function doesn't suffice.  So my question remains:  aren't there *any* other functions for which Lesbegue integration is required?

Comment: well, the easiest type of function to plot is one that only takes on two values, i.e indicator functions. However, to produce something not Riemann-integrable, we need to produce a badly behaved set, so that we get a positive measure of discontinuities. This is certainly not “drawable” or “approximately plottable” (besides arbitrarily putting a bunch of dots when sketching on a blackboard). Fat Cantor sets (as mentioned above) serve this purpose very well (and are very important sets to know for any analysis student independent of this particular question).

Comment: again, I strongly believe that motivating in any sense Lebesgue integration as “we can integrate more functions” is completely the wrong way to go. Lebesgue and Riemann have the same philosophy (I say this despite the usual horizontal/vertical argument); the purpose of integrals is to add “many” things up, and both Lebesgue and Riemann do this perfectly (Riemann sums vs simple functions, followed by suitable limits). So, while it’s good to know Lebesgue integrable functions which are not Riemann integrable, that’s not really the point of the theory.

Comment: Just a warning here, to reiterate. Even the (indicator function of the) usual Cantor set gives rise to an uncountable set of discontinuities, but it has measure zero. Thus, you stay in Riemann integrability territory. This is beyond a countability/uncountability issue. There's another philosophical point re the students: In practice, if you ever typicallly want to calculate a Lebesgue integral, you use Riemann integration (perhaps with dominated convergence, etc.).

Comment: Apart from boundedness, the chief restriction of Riemann is that the domain is partitioned into a finite number of pieces. With Lebesgue you can go countably wild.